# Better pattern than nested if statements for flow control

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

Can anyone suggest a better pattern for processing a number of steps like this?

The only other way I can think of now is using exceptions for flow control but I've read that it is not advisable because it is basically a goto statement.

```
if (FileHandler.CheckIfNewFilesExist(sourceFolderPath))
            {
                if (FileHandler.MoveFolder(sourceFolderPath, temporyFolderPath))
                {
                    if (CSVHandler.AppendUniqueIdToCSV(temporyFolderPath, filesToBeAppended))
                    {
                        FileHandler.CopyFolder(temporyFolderPath, finalFolderPath);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Looks reasonable for 4 steps. I wouldn't look for a different solution  if you don't have a significantly larger number of steps (>=10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use &&

```
if (FileHandler.CheckIfNewFilesExist(sourceFolderPath)
    && FileHandler.MoveFolder(sourceFolderPath, temporyFolderPath)
    && CSVHandler.AppendUniqueIdToCSV(temporyFolderPath, filesToBeAppended))            
{
    FileHandler.CopyFolder(temporyFolderPath, finalFolderPath);
}
```

Comment: Seems obvious now that I've seen it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could make a fluent interface pretty easily that does this:

```
FileHandler.CheckIfNewFilesExist(sourceFolderPath)
    .ThenIf(() => FileHandler.MoveFolder(sourceFolderPath, temporyFolderPath))
    .ThenIf(() =>
        CSVHandler.AppendUniqueIdToCSV(temporyFolderPath, filesToBeAppended))
    .ThenDo(() => FileHandler.CopyFolder(temporyFolderPath, finalFolderPath));
```

Here they are:

```
public static class BooleanEx
{
    public static bool ThenIf(this bool @this, Func<bool> that)
    {
        return @this ? that() : false;
    }

    public static void ThenDo(this bool @this, Action action)
    {
        if (@this)
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good article on flattening those structures can be found on [Coding Horror.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)
There is no point in me pasting it here.

Answer (score 1):

In your case all the conditions can be combined into a single `if` using the `&&` operator but if there were some extra code in each `if` block you could invert the `if`'s:

```
if (!FileHandler.CheckIfNewFilesExist(sourceFolderPath))
  return;
// Perhaps some more code ...
if (!FileHandler.MoveFolder(sourceFolderPath, temporyFolderPath))
  return;
// Perhaps some more code ...
if (!CSVHandler.AppendUniqueIdToCSV(temporyFolderPath, filesToBeAppended))
  return;
FileHandler.CopyFolder(temporyFolderPath, finalFolderPath);
```

You obviously have to extract your code into a method to be able to use `return`.